# C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have some codes in my project and under below codes gives warning;

```
 private var viewController: UIViewController? {
        for var next:UIView? = self.superview; next != nil; next = next?.superview {
            let responder = next?.nextResponder()
            if let vc = responder as? UIViewController {
                return vc
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Warning line under below:

```
for var next:UIView? = self.superview; next != nil; next = next?.superview {
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 basicly yes but my line doesnt fix with it

Comment: can you show me that code????

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 i added top side warning line you can see yellow line

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 any idea? how can i fix ? this line

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 ty man shadow fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you rewrite your code with `while` cycle:

```
var viewController: UIViewController? {
    var next: UIView? = self.superview
    while next != nil {
        let responder = next?.nextResponder()
        if let vc = responder as? UIViewController {
            return vc
        }
        next = next?.superview
    }
    return nil
}
```